# Limitations on FusionTables layers in google maps

Tags: google-maps

I am using the KML fusion tables styling to colour-code the regions of the UK with a distinct colour. I have successfuly colour-coded 4 regions, but it does not allow me to add more regions from the table. I have added and a second layer, but again the regions are not colour-coded. Does this have to do with the limitation of KML fusion tables? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fusion Tables styling</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
var map, layer, layer2;

function initialize() {

var leicester = new google.maps.LatLng(52.62, -1.13);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  center: leicester,
  zoom: 6
});
layerMap();
secondLayerMap();
}

function layerMap(){
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'geometry',
  from: '1vBKVuQNY4d8ncgg0fbgaXxDxsSdPtJMka2KsxnUZ'
},
styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    fillOpacity: 1.0
  }
}, {
  where: 'HECTARES = 7877200',
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#0000FF'
  }
}, {
  where: 'HECTARES = 159469.844',
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#FF4000'
  }
}, {
  where: 'HECTARES = 1300379.625',
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#FFFFFF'
  }
}, {
  where: 'HECTARES = 1940521.5',
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#FFFF00'
 }
}]
});
layer.setMap(map);
}
function secondLayerMap(){
layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'geometry',
  from: '1xtYFs7V7qYTwNfb2xRweXO7pY_0Y83Vom5NnYQ4-'
},
styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    fillOpacity: 1.0
  }
}, {
  where: 'HECTARES = 2122463.25',
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#0404B4'
  }
}, {
  where: 'HECTARES = 1556405.5',
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#61380B'
  }
}]
});
layer2.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FusionTables allows a maximum of 5 tables to a map, a maximum of 5 dynamic styles to *one* of those layers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer#limits

> You can use the Maps API to add up to five Fusion Tables layers to a map, one of which can be styled with up to five styling rules.

If you apply the colors via the FusionTables UI (assign a color from a column to the polygons), you can use as many colors as you like in as many of those layers as you like.  It is only the styles assigned dynamically via javascript that have the 5 in one layer limitation.

Comment: I have two tables so far. The first one has 4 coloured regions and the other has 2. When I try to add another colour to the first table it does not display it on the region. The second table doesn't work at all for some reason.

Comment: As the documentation says `You can use the Maps API to add up to five Fusion Tables layers to a map, **one** of which can be styled with up to five styling rules.`  You have 5 rules, the default style, plus four unique polygons.

Comment: It is a documented limitation of FusionTables.  As I said in my answer, you can use the user interface to assign colors to the polygons from a column.

Comment: All I am doing is that I'm querying the columns of the table to add new colours. Is it required to modify the table and add something?

Comment: Yes, if you want to overcome the limitation on 5 styles on one of 5 FusionTablesLayers.