# How to use data from two Google Fusion tables?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to create a google map of "service areas" in USA & Canada, stumbled upon this fusion table layer stuff & thought it would work out great, but I am having problems.

1. I cannot create a fusion table & make it public without paying google, no way around that, I'll use existing public tables.
2. I need to apply styles to the fusion table layer, BUT I am loading 2 fusion tables (layers) & the API only allows styles to be added to one layer.

Here is my code:

```
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      // Styles a map in night mode.
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 40.237395466608156, lng: -93.68512878417971},
        zoom: 3.9,
        styles: []

      });

      var usa_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: 'geometry',
          from: '1ZZ8j0NDbs2dilcQWjLh9xI7qIJso6DgYAoGTbA',
          where: "STATE IN ('North Dakota', 'Minnesota', 'Wisconsin', 'Ohio', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Illinois', 'Kentucky', 'Missouri', 'Tennessee', 'Arkansas', 'Florida', 'Alabama', 'Mississippi', 'Louisiana', 'Texas', 'Oklahoma', 'Kansas', 'Nebraska', 'South Dakota')",
        },
        styles: [
          { 
            polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: "#006db7",
            strokeColor: "#006db7",
            fillOpacity: ".5",
          },
        }],

        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
      });

      var canada_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: 'geometry',
          from: '1auwG6s4axorHR-QAX3UDXL544pSEXlbxmyu6xvJC',
          where: "Place IN ('Quebec', 'Ontario', 'Manitoba')",

        },
        styles: [
          { 
            polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: "#006db7",
            strokeColor: "#006db7",
            fillOpacity: ".5",
          },
        }],

        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
      });

    };

  </script>
```

So:

1. Is there a way to use the fusion table polygon data locally? i.e. export the CSV and load that?
2. Is there a way to load data from (join) 2 fusion tables in one map layer?
3. is there another option I am overlooking?

Comment: Use the FusionTable UI to style the FusionTable, there is no limit on styling that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limitations on FusionTables layers in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661712/limitations-on-fusiontables-layers-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the fusion table polygon data locally? i.e. export the CSV and load that?

Yes, a [Fusion Table can be downloaded as KML](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2548807?hl=en), which you can use third-party apps/libraries such as [toGeoJson](https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson) to load in the app as [GeoJSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/data#Data.addGeoJson).

> Is there a way to load data from (join) 2 fusion tables in one map layer?

You'd have to [merge the tables through the Fusion Tables UI](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171254?hl=en) into one Fusion Table and load that layer.

> is there another option I am overlooking?

Yes, as the first part of your message is incorrect: "I cannot create a fusion table & make it public without paying google...."

You can create [Public or Unlisted](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171221?hl=en) Fusion Tables without having to pay Google.

Also, when going to your [created Fusion Table in the UI](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232), selecting `Tools->Publish` and selecting "Get HTML and JavaScript", you'll see the following undocumented option "`options`" for the `FusionTablesLayer`:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col12",
    from: "1ClpNLfPQnhEex1KvGg5FrHPgzXgSu1ZvFEL9a2l1",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});
```

You can use that `options` to override the default styling that the Javascript API applies and use the style you defined in the Fusion Tables UI.

Here is a [simple sample JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zuzohohele/edit?html,output) showing the Fusion Table style defined in the Javascript for `usa_geometry` while the Fusion Table style defined in the Fusion Tables UI for `canada_geometry`:
[image]

Comment: very helpful indeed! thanks.   Though I really can't create a public doc - I have one of those legacy free business accounts & there are just no options to create a public document available to people outside my organization.